# JSON.NET JSON to XML conversion with timezones

Tags: json, xml, json.net, timezone-offset

I am probably missing something here, but when I use:

```
doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json)
```

To convert the following:

```
{ DATA: { date1: '2017-01-04T15:03:25+00:00', date2: '2017-01-03T15:05:50+00:00', date3: '2017-01-06T10:14:55+00:00', date4: '2017-08-09T09:27:07+00:00'}}
```

I get:

```
<DATA>
<date1>2017-01-04T16:03:25+01:00</date1>
<date2>2017-01-03T16:05:50+01:00</date2>
<date3>2017-01-06T11:14:55+01:00</date3>
<date4>2017-08-09T11:27:07+02:00</date4>
</DATA>
```

It's 1 hour ahead of GMT where I am, but why is the last date converted to 2 hours ahead?

A related question, if I am doing only JSON parsing I get to use a **JsonSerializerSettings** object to further refine how these dates are handled. Is there an equivalent for parsing to XML?

**EDIT**: OK so the answer to the first part seems to be due to the change to summer time. Still unsure about the second part.